# train weights using SVM

Tags: matlab, svm

I have the following dataset example

```
sample   f1    f2    f3   f4    X
samp01   0.7   0.4   0.2  0.5   0.9
samp02  ................
```

I need to find the weights that minimize the error using SVM, i.e. the weights that minimize the following error function

X - (w1*f1 + w2*f2 + w3*f3 + w4*f4), where -1 <= w <= 1

Comment: There's loads of functions built-in for support vector machines, such as `templateSVM`, `predict` etc

Comment: @rayryeng don't use that, see the docs: `svmtrain will be removed in a future release. See fitcsvm, ClassificationSVM, and CompactClassificationSVM instead.`

Comment: @Adriaan I have R2014a where I am... no signs of deprecation. I'll consult the docs via MathWorks next time.

Comment: but I don't have labels (class). is still possible? can you give an  example

Comment: SVMs are **supervised** learning algorithms.  You need labels.  Without them, there would be **many** solutions that would give you weights that minimize the cost function.  If you don't have labels, consider using something from the Optimization Toolbox: `fminunc, fmincon`, etc.